# How set the string format in editText

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I want the string being displayed in my EditText like as:

`"AA-BB-11"`, but i need only put inside `AABB11`, it's possible ?

Comment: You have `"AA-BB-11"` and you want `AABB11`? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to implement TextWatcher. Try something like that :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText test = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText) 
        test.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
      if (text.length() == 2 || text.length() == 5) {
        text.append('-');
      }
    }
```

See : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

**EDIT :**

You can see full code here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043245/6450234.

You have just to change `text.length() == 3 || text.length() == 7` by `text.length() == 2 || text.length() == 5`